# Load a black and white image into an binary array

Tags: java, arrays, image, find, union

I'm building a program that can recognise images from the air.

I am able to load the image and convert it to black and white, but I'm having trouble attempting to get the pixel values into an array so that I can use a union find to link clusters of white pixels and black pixels.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class Image {

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            new Image();
        }

        public Image()
        {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Image");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);            //closes application properly
                    frame.add(new ImagePane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }


    public class ImagePane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage image;
        private BufferedImage bwImage;


        public ImagePane() {
            try {
                FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
                image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/Connor/Desktop/image.jpg"));
                this.image = image;

                bwImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
                this.bwImage = bwImage;

                Graphics2D g2d = bwImage.createGraphics();
                g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
                g2d.dispose();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            Dimension size = super.getPreferredSize();
            if (image != null) {
                size = new Dimension(image.getWidth() * 2, image.getHeight());
            }
            return size;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (image != null) {

                int x = (getWidth() - (image.getWidth() * 2)) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - (image.getHeight()));

                g.drawImage(image, x, y, this);
                x += image.getWidth();
                g.drawImage(bwImage, x, y, this);
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

I'm hoping to get some output like the following:

```
        { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 }
```

Comment: Try using a `BitSet`. Iterate through your image and set the bits (so 1 for white and 0 for black)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a way to do this would be using a `BitSet`.

A small code example how to go about this:

```
//img is your black and white image of type BufferedImage

// Get the width and height of your image
int width = img.getWidth();
int height = img.getHeight();

// create a BitSet of the correct size      
BitSet bits = new BitSet(width * height);

// Iterate through your image's pixels and set the correct bits.
for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
    {
        // Check against 0xffffffff which is the RGB value of white.
        if (img.getRGB(x, y) == 0xffffffff)
        {
            bits.set(y * width + x);
        }
    }
}
```

After this you have a BitSet with a set bit representing the color white and an unset bit representing the color black. You can now do mathematical analysis on that as you please.

Comment: Thanks very much for that! I hadn't come across BitSet before but it seems to do what I need.

Its outputting the positions of the white pixels from what I can tell, just need to figure out how to link them now!

Comment: The BitSet is basically a one dimensional array of bits (which is the simplest way to safe a value that is either 1 or 0 (or here white or black)).
In order to make it "two dimensional" you need to do some calculation on the index. Basically it's `current row * number of columns + current column` so if you want to access [2][4] in a 6x6 array it is `2 * 6 + 4`. In Java it is generally faster to use a one dimensional array over a two dimensional array (although it gets harder to read and maintain and therefore using a 2d array might still just be better for a use case)